# Kubernetes strange behavior with Persistent Volume Claim and volumeMounts

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, persistent-volumes

I can't understand why there are differences in the pod filesystem, when this is deployed using a volumeMount, compared to the same pod but without a volumeMount, in details using the following deployment file :

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: error-manager
  name: error-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: error-manager
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: error-manager
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: almaviva.jfrog.io/conversational-tech-docker/error-manager:1.0.4
        name: error-manager
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8001
        resources: {}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: conv-ai-reg
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: error-manager
  name: error-manager
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8001-8001
    port: 8001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8001
  selector:
    app: error-manager
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The pod has the following files with their respective sizes in the /sqlite path:

```
root@error-manager-54db47994c-brfsh:/sqlite# ls -l
total 980
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 376832 Mar  4 10:26 db.sqlite3
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 626688 Mar  4 10:26 db2.sqlite3
```

Instead defining a PVC and modifying the Deployment as follows:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: sqlite-pv-claim-error-manager
spec:
  storageClassName: nfs-azurefile-csi-premium
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 8Gi
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: error-manager
  name: error-manager
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: error-manager
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
      labels:
        app: error-manager
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: almaviva.jfrog.io/conversational-tech-docker/error-manager:1.0.4
        name: error-manager
        ports:
          - containerPort: 8001
        volumeMounts:
          - name: sqlite-persistent-volume
            mountPath: /sqlite
        resources: {}
        imagePullPolicy: Always
      imagePullSecrets:
        - name: conv-ai-reg
      volumes:
      - name: sqlite-persistent-volume
        persistentVolumeClaim:
          claimName: sqlite-pv-claim-error-manager
status: {}
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    app: error-manager
  name: error-manager
spec:
  ports:
  - name: 8001-8001
    port: 8001
    protocol: TCP
    targetPort: 8001
  selector:
    app: error-manager
  type: ClusterIP
status:
  loadBalancer: {}
```

The pod has the following files with their respective sizes:

```
root@error-manager-5ff767b9cb-s57wv:/sqlite# ls -lh
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 0 Mar  5 00:12 db.sqlite3
root@error-manager-5ff767b9cb-s57wv:/sqlite#
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: It sounds like the image already contains the data files.  The volume mount will always hide what was in the image; nothing copies files into a volume for you.  You may find running a relational database in a separate StatefulSet easier to manage, and it will be possible to run more than 1 replica of your application container this way.

Comment: To add to @DavidMaze's comment. If you use a Deployment, then you can't use the same PVC as Kubernetes will attempt to mount the same disk onto both pods and if both pods are on different nodes, the second will never start. This is where StatefulSets are useful as the pods on these each get a different disk and will always get the same disk.

Comment: @DavidMaze the use case is not to use an external relational db, however the Dockerfile executes the following command:
```
COPY sqlite/ ./sqlite
```
By declaring a volumeMount in the pod deployment, the docker-image files should be copied, as specified in the Dockerfile, at least that's what I've always done:\

Comment: Nothing auto-copies files into Kubernetes volumes.  There's a confusing Docker feature where this happens in some cases, but it doesn't work with anything other than empty named volumes and it only happens when directly using Docker.  I'd avoid relying on this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

When you recreated the pod it will have deleted all the data that was on the container's filesystem.

Have you re-run whatever data ingestion put the data into that database, and then checked the size?

Comment: Copying the files inside the pod after its startup, they persist in the volume even after the pod is restarted

Answer (score 0):

You might want to run the following command to [inspect](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/inspect/#:%7E:text=docker%20image%20inspect-,docker%20image%20inspect,-Description) the image created.

```
docker image inspect -f json
```

If you created the image, you may use -o out [flag](https://docs.docker.com/reference/cli/docker/image/build/#:%7E:text=When%20building%20the%20Dockerfile,binary%3A) on the command to create a log

```
docker build -o out .
```